# Jiggling Element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I want an HTML element to jiggle around one spot.

I tried to do this with scriptaculous and some combined move functions from it, but none of the results were satisfying.

Comment: So what did you try, what was unsatisfying about it? How was it wrong? What mark-up are you using? Can you post a live-demo (on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/),perhaps)?

Comment: I combined many scriptaculous move effects. Each effect was fired after the previous. But it looked to liner and not smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[That's it!](http://daneden.me/animate/) Animate.css does some really nice css3 animations.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/vibrate/ ?

Comment: Thanks, but this one uses jQuery :/ The animation should be slow an minimal.

Comment: Yeah, but looking at the code should give you a good idea of how to replicate it with scriptaculous, no?